# Moderator Pro Tempore Nomination Thread

Tags: discussion, moderation

This thread is for nominations to be a temporary moderator to help the community get started.  See this [Blog Post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) for more details.

Selection Criteria:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

To nominate:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.

Comment: We should put heavy weight on participation on the [latex]/[tex] tags on SO.

Comment: This should be CW.

Comment: Also look at stats page for [latex] on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=latex&sort=stats&pagesize=50

Comment: @Charles - it was intended as CW.  I thought I had checked the box, but apparently didn't.

Answer (score 13):

## [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey)

### [(meta.tex)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey)

#### Accept

He is one of the [top contributors of **MathOverflow**](https://mathoverflow.net/users/45/andrew-stacey), and since the beginning of this private beta he has been following closely the evolution of this site and its community, contributing with questions and answers on the parent site and proposing features in this meta site.

Comment: Apologies for leaving it so long before officially accepting!  (I hope no-one was misled.)

Comment: Great! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 9):

## Scott Morrison

([main site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/77/scott-morrison)) ([meta site](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/77/scott-morrison)) ([mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3/scott-morrison))

Moderator on MathOverflow, where I think he's shown all the qualities required in a moderator (and more!).  In particular, he's *visible* without being *overbearing*.

Comment: @Scott Morrison: in case you're tempted to decline through being busy enough already with MO, may I remind you that this is for moderator _pro tempore_ and your experience would be invaluable.

Answer (score 7):

## [Konrad Rudolph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/42/konrad-rudolph)

### [(meta.tex)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42/konrad-rudolph) [(latex on SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:1968+%5Blatex%5D)

Accept.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for the shameless self-promotion

## [Juan A. Navarro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/169/juan-a-navarro)

[(meta.tex)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/169/juan-a-navarro)

Enthusiastic TeX/LaTeX user. Runs a small site for LaTeX beginners in spanish: [LaTeX Fácil](http://navarroj.com/latex/). Once very active at [es-tex](http://listserv.rediris.es/cgi-bin/wa?A0=ES-TEX), the mailing list of spanish speaking TeX users, and on a few occasions contributed in [comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/search?q=juan+navarro).

Comment: Believe or not, I was going to nominate you. You were one of the top contributors users during the definition phase in Area51.

Comment: Thank You Julian!

Answer (score 6):

## Vivi

([main site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14/vivi)) ([meta site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14/vivi))

Very active on the main site (less so on meta).

My main reason for proposing her is as a way to ensure that there is an "outside" voice at the heart of the community here.  By "outside" I mean someone not used to the SO framework and someone (as she admits herself!) not all that expert on the nitty-gritty of (La)TeX.

Comment: She has also proven to be very enthusiastic about TeX/LaTeX and this site itself, which is a great quality we would like in a moderator.

Answer (score 5):

## Julian Lamas-Rodriguez

([main site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/165/julian-lamas-rodriguez)) ([meta site](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/165/julian-lamas-rodriguez))

It was his idea!

Answer (score 2):

## [jalf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/148/jalf)

### [(meta.tex)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/148/jalf)

A top contributor during the definition phase in Area51, he promoted the site [in his own blog](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/06/texoverflow-com-sounds-good/). That's love! :)

Comment: Wow, really? I almost declined (check the edit history), but on thinking about it for a minute, I guess I could live with it considering this is just a temporary deal. I want this site to get off to a good start, but in the long term, I don't think moderatorship is for me. I guess I'll let the nomination stay, and see what happens. :)

Comment: That's great! :)

Answer (score 2):

## Caramdir

([main site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/83/caramdir) [meta site](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/83/caramdir))

As well as his activity on both sites, I've been impressed by his politeness (not sure if that's quite the right word, but hopefully it's close enough).